# Нужна ли между местоимениями запятая или нет?

Tags: запятые, местоимения

Всё никак не могу найти ответ на вопрос: нужна ли между местоимениями запятая или нет? Например: я тебя хочу спросить. Между "я" и "тебя" нужна запятая?

Comment: Почему, по вашему мнению, ее необходимо тут поставить?

Comment: потому что разделяет? или я не права и запятая здесь лишняя?

Comment: Для того, чтобы поставить знак препинания (где бы то ни было), необходима какая-то причина. На основании какого правила вы предполагаете, что здесь можно говорить о необходимости постановки запятой?

Comment: О, наконец-то проснулись те, кто это делает! Ура!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Давно хотел спросить (так и не понял). "...наконец-то проснулись те, кто это делает!" – это о чём?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: я про тех, кто ставит такие нелепые запятые.)) Это уже прогресс, если они подвергают их сомнению и тем самым встают на вдумчивый путь.